# How to create a Mininet VLAN

Tags: python, mininet, vlan

I am using Mininet to simulate a network I am trying to create. Is there a way to setup switches to use VLANs? I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> From GitHub:
>
> vlanhost.py:
>   An example of how to subclass Host to use a VLAN on its primary interface.

[Mininet Examples](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/f530c99415d8215a0ab7dba4b55e7a64297dd268/examples/README.md)
[Mininet Python API Reference Manua](http://mininet.org/api/annotated.html)